# Mapping WebForm to data transfer object

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, mvp, webforms

I'm implementing the MVP pattern within an existing asp.net webforms application and I was wondering if there is a clean way to map my form data to a data transfer object. I'm not particularly fond of implementing it this way:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject()
{
    obj.Name = txtName.Text,
    obj.Description = txtDescription.Text,
    obj.SomeOtherValue = txtOtherValue.Text
};
```

Does anyone have any suggestions of a better way to tackle this problem so that I don't have to write a mapping method for every data transfer object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring.Net provides framework for bidirectional data mapping.

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html#web-databinding

It will be a bit complicated only for this feature. But it does provide other useful benefits as well e.g. (Dependency injection, Validation Framework, Navigation framework etc)

Comment: I was kind of hoping there was a solution without bringing in another framework

Answer (score 0):

[XForms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms) is one of the most elegant way, but still in its beta...

Otherwise you just need to add a Controller between HTML and your model, read more about MVC design pattern. The Controller will convert `*.Text` into your model incoming parameters. In other words it will *decouple* your view from model.